# arduino esp32 +ov7670 camera want to connect web but fail

Tags: arduino, camera

I saw this lesson [here](https://bitluni.net/ov7670-with-fifo)
I just have esp32 board and camera,I do not have display
so I have to show my camera image on my web,I have set my wifi to connect,
but it still dont work. I do not know how can I do..
please help me thanks.
code:

```
const char* ssid = "mywifi";
const char* password = "eee";
 const int VSYNC = 32; //vertical sync
//set up pin...


void loop() 
{
  Serial . println ("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  startCameraServer();

  Serial.print("Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");
  while(!digitalRead(VSYNC));
  while(digitalRead(VSYNC));
  camera.prepareCapture();
  camera.startCapture();
  while(!digitalRead(VSYNC));
  camera.stopCapture();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your complete webserver functionality is missing, you will probably never see anything in the broswer.

Use the built in example in the Arduino IDE and change the camera pins to your setup:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\ESP32\examples\Camera\CameraWebServer
```

and open `CameraWebServer.ino`

and you will see how much code your program misses.